# rounding time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, format, rounding

I had a problem with the time format of postgresql
example: 00: 01: 48.235294
I want to round to 2 seconds only digits after the decimal >> 00: 01: 48.24
does this work? please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to a timestamp(2), e.g.

```
select value::timestamp(2)
```

If you're really just using time I think you can also do, e.g.

```
select value::time(2)
```